# Is there an alternative to numpy.average() that can average along an axis whilst using numpypy?

Tags: python, numpy, pypy

I'm trying to make some code run faster by using `pypy`. However, whenever I run the code using `pypy`, I get an error from `pypy`'s `numpy` equivalent (`numpypy`).

In my usual code I use...

```
numpy.average(array, axis=0)
```

in order to average an array along a particular axis.

When running the same code using pypy and numpypy, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: average() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

I could use a `for` loop to go through the array and average individual elements but this would take a long time and (I would imagine) not provide the speed that I would like.

**Is there an alternative to numpy.average() that can average along an axis whilst using numpypy?**

Comment: "not provide the speed that I would like": did you measure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to use the `weights` parameter, you can use `mean` instead (1.9.1-dev0 -- not sure when it was introduced):

```
>>>> import numpypy as np
>>>> a = np.arange(2*3).reshape(2,3)
>>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>>> np.mean(a, axis=0)
array([ 1.5,  2.5,  3.5])
>>>> np.mean(a, axis=1)
array([ 1.,  4.])
>>>> a.mean(axis=0)
array([ 1.5,  2.5,  3.5])
>>>> a.mean(axis=1)
array([ 1.,  4.])
```